# Combining two time-based queries from the same set of data

Tags: mysql, timezone

I've got a database that contains events across multiple sites in two time zones, and all report the local time. I need to get the last 12 hours of data and put it in a CSV. I put in a union, and while it outputs data without the ORDER BY, I get an alias error when I run it with the INTO OUTFILE section. What am I missing?

```
(SELECT
    comp.locationid,
    comp.name,
    event.status,
    event.starttime,
    event.endtime
FROM
    comp,event
WHERE
    event.endtime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
    AND event.endtime < NOW()
    AND event.compid = comp.id
    AND comp.timezone = "EST")


UNION


(SELECT
    comp.locationid,
    comp.name,
    event.status,
    event.starttime,
    event.endtime
FROM
    comp,event
WHERE
    event.endtime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 HOUR)
    AND event.endtime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    AND event.compid = comp.id
    AND comp.timezone = "PST")


ORDER BY comp.locationid
INTO OUTFILE
    "report.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
;
```

Comment: give alias to each table.

Comment: This is my first time using SQL, and the documentation is confusing. How do I alias the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

1. You can't refer to a particular table name in `ORDER BY` clause in `UNION`. That being said just change

   ```
   ORDER BY comp.locationid
            ^^^^^
   ```

   to simply

   ```
   ORDER BY locationid
   ```
2. Besides it seems that you most likely meant to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. So change that too because `UNION` takes extra processing steps to eliminate duplicates.
3. Remove parentheses around both `SELECT`s in `UNION`
4. Change all double quotes to single quotes

Comment: `UNION ALL` and the change in reference does the trick, but now I'm getting a general error at `INTO OUTFILE`

Comment: Try to change all double quotes to single quotes and please post the **exact** error message you're getting

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE
        'report.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINA' at line 35

Comment: Remove parentheses around both `SELECT`s. They are causing your problem and you don't need them anyway

Answer (score 0):

Giving alias to tables would help

```
(SELECT
    comp.locationid,
    comp.name,
    event.status,
    event.starttime,
    event.endtime
FROM
    comp,event
WHERE
    event.endtime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
    AND event.endtime < NOW()
    AND event.compid = comp.id
    AND comp.timezone = "EST") AS T


UNION ALL


(SELECT
    comp.locationid,
    comp.name,
    event.status,
    event.starttime,
    event.endtime
FROM
    comp,event
WHERE
    event.endtime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 HOUR)
    AND event.endtime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
    AND event.compid = comp.id
    AND comp.timezone = "PST") AS T2
ORDER BY comp.locationid
INTO OUTFILE
    "report.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
;
```